# Java md5 hash of same string from web service is different for every transaction

Tags: java, web-services, md5

I'm trying to compare passwords in java coming from a web service.

I invoke the service from command line with the following:

curl -d '[{"usr":"joe","password":"joe"}]'  http://mydomain.com:8080/myservice/login

I parse the JSON and pass the password to a hash method.

My hashing method is as follows:

```
 private String createHash(String password){

    byte[] bytesOfMessage = null;
    try {
        bytesOfMessage = password.getBytes("UTF-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    MessageDigest md = null;
    try {
        md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    String thedigest = md.digest(bytesOfMessage).toString();
    System.out.println("passed in: "+thedigest);

    return thedigest;
}
```

The problem is that the hash that is printed is different everytime I invoke this method with the exact same password.  How can I have the passwords come out with the same hash so I can compare the passwords and authenticate a user?

Thanks!

Comment: Please tell me you're using https in production ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the `digest()` method is returning you a `byte[]`, and the `toString()` method on `byte[]` is printing out the *object identity* of the byte array, not the *content*.  generally, in order to print out the results of a byte[], you need to convert the bytes to a printable string (often using hex encoding or base64 encoding).  hex encoding is frequently used for md5 checksums, [example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9655181/convert-from-byte-array-to-hex-string-in-java).

Comment: A simple call to `Arrays.toString(byte[])` will suffice if you just want to see the contents of the byte array, but is probably not appropriate for storing in a database if that's what you're after.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with base64.I have given the example

```
public String encrypt(String plaintext) throws Exception {

        MessageDigest messageDigest = null;
        String hash=null;

        try{
            messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
            messageDigest.update(plaintext.getBytes("UTF8"));
            byte[] raw = messageDigest.digest();
            hash = new String(Base64.encode(raw));


        }catch(Exception nsa){
        throw new Exception();
        }

            return hash;

}
```